# Browser doesn't send FQDN in Origin header

Tags: http, cross-domain, cors, fqdn

In the context of CORS, is it possible to coerce the browser to always send the Origin header with an FQDN? The target service should see `Origin: http://website.intranet.example.com/page.html` instead of `Origin: http://website/page.html`.

As the example implies this is an intranet environment and the goal is to filter request origins by subdomain to allow any page hosted on a domain machine (`*.intranet.example.com`) to make cross-origin requests to the service which is also hosted in the same domain. The problem (if you will) is that intranet sites are commonly addressed as `http://website/` with the remainder implied by the connection-specific DNS suffix: `intranet.example.com` set via domain policy.

The only workaround I can think of is to require all the 'origin' pages to force canonical URLs (i.e. redirect `//foo` to `//foo.intranet.example.com`) with the least side effect of "ugly URLs".

Answer (score 0):

In the CORS context, rather than trying to get Origin values the same for the short and the fully qualified domain name, you could just focus on whether the server should allow the request to proceed or not whether either Origin value is present:

Assuming that to allow the cross-origin request, the responding server only needs to respond with a suitable Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header, you could respond with the wildcard value to say any incoming Origin is ok:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

If your client requires a specific domain instead of the wildcard, you could have the webserver just echo back the value of the incoming Origin header if you choose to allow the request to proceed, regardless of what the Origin value says it is.

e.g. in Apache, use the SetEnvIf and Header modules to write an environment variable containing the origin value if that value matches a specific regex, then if that variable exists write the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header with the environment variable's value:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "(.+)" origin_header_value=$1
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{origin_header_value}e" env=origin_header_value
```

If you need more fine grain control over whether the webserver includes the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in this manner, you can just set a more restrictive regex in the SetEnvIf command instead of using `.+`.

Comment: The problem is that `Origin: http://server1/` is ambiguous. Request could be a legitimate from a page on `server1.intranet.example.com` or `server1` could be a malicious machine on some LAN; this applies when a domain user is remote and using VPN or DirectAccess to access the intranet.

Comment: That could be true of any http request though it sounds like you're looking to determine request legitimacy based off the Origin header value, but that is not a good way to determine malicious requests  - you can make http requests with any values set in them.  Perhaps you can add additional checking of the incoming IP addresses against a whitelist? Or add some http authorization or assume that if you can determine that the request arrives through the VPN that it should already be allowed? - that may depend if its a closed or open intranet.

Comment: User navigates to `http://evil-comp/page.html` (not-domain server) which makes AJAX calls to `http://payroll.intranet.example.com/confidential` and then forwards that data elsewhere. A proper CORS policy will prevent `http://evil-comp/page.html` from seeing contents of the response.

Comment: But yes you are correct, it's possible to make an http request to steal the same data, however that will require the attacker to execute code on a domain machine under the user's credentials - but that's a whole other attack vector unrelated to CORS.

Comment: Just to understand this a bit more - is this a scenario where you are connected to a VPN, but there are no company DNS servers added for address resolution? I'm wondering if you could allow the resource on the  `payroll` servers to only be viewed when the request is from specific known Origin values (setup for both short or fqdn) and enforce that the VPN's DNS takes first precedence in domain name resolution and resolves both the short and fqdn names to the correct location?

Comment: VPN/DA clients machines _do_ have private company DNS servers as primary forced by domain policy (and must be domain-joined). I think you're alluding to a DNS hijacking scenario where a LAN DNS tried to pass off `good-server` as `good-server.intranet.example.com`. I'm concerned about when resolution falls back to a LAN DNS server to resolve `evil-comp` because there's no `evil-comp.intranet.example.com`. I guess that shifts the problem from CORS to DNSSEC/NRPT.

Comment: Yeah it sounds like it, if `evil-comp` fails back to LAN DNS because there's no `evil-comp.intranet.example.com`, any requests that malicious page makes to the webservers should still include Origin as `evil-comp`, which (assuming they are adequately configured) could deny the request and return nothing of any consequence. The webservers probably just need to be setup to only allow known Origins.  It might be that if its quite important, doing like you suggest and have webservers force short name requests to redirect to the fqdn might be best depending on how much you trust the DNS resolution.